# Unable to execute command in ssh with Jsch

Tags: java, jsch

I am unable to execute below command in ssh getting error incorrect usage whereas same I am able to execute manually code is given as

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String host="";
    String user="";
    String password="";
    //String command1="mml";
    String command2="mml hgsdp:msisdn=919051018408";

    try{
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");

        Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
        //((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command1);
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command2);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
        InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect();
        byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
        while(true){
            while(in.available()>0){
                int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if(i<0)break;
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }               
            if(channel.isClosed()){
                System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception ee){}
        }
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a stacktrace?

Comment: Incorrect usage
Usage: mml [-a] [-c] [-s | -Q] [-d device] [-i device | -I device] [-y lines]
       mml [-s] [-d device] [-i device | -I device] [-r time] [-w time] command...
       mml [-b] [-c] [-s] [-l line] [-r time] [-w time] -f file
exit-status: 2

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by MML working only with Telnet, that is according to the MML documentation.